# Calculate the geographical distance in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, geopy

My dataframe:

```
DF = spark.createDataFrame([[114.038696,  22.5315,  114.047302, 22.531799], [ 114.027901, 22.5228, 114.026299, 22.5238], [ 114.026299, 22.5238,114.024597,22.5271], [114.024597,  22.5271,114.024696,22.527201]], list('ABCD'))
DF.show()
+----------+-------+----------+---------+
|         A|      B|         C|        D|
+----------+-------+----------+---------+
|114.038696|22.5315|114.047302|22.531799|
|114.027901|22.5228|114.026299|  22.5238|
|114.026299|22.5238|114.024597|  22.5271|
|114.024597|22.5271|114.024696|22.527201|
+----------+-------+----------+---------+
```

`(A, B)` & `(C, D)` are coordinates of two points;

`column A` & `column C` are longitude;

`column B` & `column D` are latitude;

I want to calculate the geographical distance between the two points.

I try to:

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic
DF = DF.withColumn('Lengths/m', geodesic((['B'],['A']), (['D'],['C'])).m)
```

Then I get the error:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

What should I do differently to successfully calculate the geographical distance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define a custom [user-defined-function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html):

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

@F.udf(returnType=FloatType())
def geodesic_udf(a, b):
    return geodesic(a, b).m


DF = DF.withColumn('Lengths/m', geodesic_udf(F.array("B", "A"), F.array("D", "C")))

DF.show()
#+----------+-------+----------+---------+---------+
#|A         |B      |C         |D        |Lengths/m|
#+----------+-------+----------+---------+---------+
#|114.038696|22.5315|114.047302|22.531799|885.94244|
#|114.027901|22.5228|114.026299|22.5238  |198.55937|
#|114.026299|22.5238|114.024597|22.5271  |405.21692|
#|114.024597|22.5271|114.024696|22.527201|15.126849|
#+----------+-------+----------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me when reproducing the example (same example dataframe) with pyspark 3.3.2. I get error: "name": "PicklingError",
 "message": "Could not serialize object: IndexError: tuple index out of range". Any idea on how to solve it?