# How to filter and select columns and merge streaming dataframes in spark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, streaming, spark-streaming

I have a streaming dataframe and I am not sure what the best way is to solve this issue

| ID | lattitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 28 | 30 |
| B | 40 | 52 |

Transform to:

| A | B. | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (28,30) | (40,52) | calculate distance |

I need to transform it to this and add a distance column in which I pass the coordinates.

I am thinking about producing 2 data streams that are filtered with all the A coordinates and B coordinates. I would then `A.join(B).withColumn(distance)` and stream the output. Is this the way to go about solving this problem?

Is there a way I could pivot without aggregation to readstream data into the format needed which could be faster than making 2 streaming dataframes filtered and merging them?

Can I add an array column of coordinates in a streaming dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how performant this will be, but you can use `pivot` to force rows of the `ID` column to become new columns and `sum` the individual latitude and longitude as a way to obtain the value itself (since there is no `F.identity`). This will get you the following result:

```
streaming_df.groupby().pivot('ID').agg(
    F.sum('latitude').alias('latitude'),
    F.sum('longitude').alias('longitude')
)

+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|A_latitude|A_longitude|B_latitude|B_longitude|
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|        28|         30|        40|         52|
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

Then you can use `F.struct` to create columns `A` and `B` using the latitude and longitude columns:

```
streaming_df.groupby().pivot('ID').agg(
    F.sum('latitude').alias('latitude'),
    F.sum('longitude').alias('longitude')
).withColumn(
    'A', F.struct(F.col('A_latitude'), F.col('A_longitude'))
).withColumn(
    'B', F.struct(F.col('B_latitude'), F.col('B_longitude'))
)

+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
|A_latitude|A_longitude|B_latitude|B_longitude|       A|       B|
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
|        28|         30|        40|         52|{28, 30}|{40, 52}|
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

The last step is to use a `udf` to calculate geographic distance, which has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70315462/5327068). Putting this all together:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from geopy.distance import geodesic

@F.udf(returnType=FloatType())
def geodesic_udf(a, b):
    return geodesic(a, b).m

streaming_df.groupby().pivot('ID').agg(
    F.sum('latitude').alias('latitude'),
    F.sum('longitude').alias('longitude')
).withColumn(
    'A', F.struct(F.col('A_latitude'), F.col('A_longitude'))
).withColumn(
    'B', F.struct(F.col('B_latitude'), F.col('B_longitude'))
).withColumn(
    'distance', geodesic_udf(F.array('B.B_longitude','B.B_latitude'), F.array('A.A_longitude','A.A_latitude'))
).select(
    'A','B','distance'
)

+--------+--------+---------+
|       A|       B| distance|
+--------+--------+---------+
|{28, 30}|{40, 52}|2635478.5|
+--------+--------+---------+
```

EDIT: When I answered your question, I let pyspark infer the datatype of each column, but I also tried to more closely reproduce the schema for your streaming dataframe by specifying the column types:

```
streaming_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("A", 28., 30.),
        ("B", 40., 52.),
    ],
    StructType([
        StructField("ID", StringType(), True),
        StructField("latitude", DoubleType(), True),
        StructField("longitude", DoubleType(), True),
    ])
)

streaming_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
```

The end result is still the same:

```
+------------+------------+---------+
|           A|           B| distance|
+------------+------------+---------+
|{28.0, 30.0}|{40.0, 52.0}|2635478.5|
+------------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: When I try to pass the coordinates, I get an error saying failed to create Point instance from Column. Do coordinates have to be in a certain format like a string? Currently, my coordinates are in the doubletype based on printschema function. Any advice on fixing this issue?

Comment: I seem to be having some trouble reproducing the error you're getting, although it's likely related to the format of your data. I went back and changed the schema of the sample data I have so that the latitude and longitude are `DoubleType`, but I still get the same result